# Transforming the text file using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-transform

```
List of countries:

'Algeria','Angola','Argentina','Australia','Austria','Bahamas','Bangladesh','Belarus','Belgium','Bhutan','Brazil','Bulgaria','Cambodia','Cameroon','Chile','China','Colombia','Cyprus','Denmark','El Salvador','Estonia','Ethiopia','Fiji','Finland','France','Georgia','Ghana','Grenada','Guinea','Haiti','Honduras','Hungary','India','Indonesia','Ireland','Italy','Japan','Kenya', 'South Korea','Liberia','Malaysia','Mexico', 'Morocco','Nepal','New Zealand','Norway','Pakistan', 'Peru','Qatar','Russia','Singapore','South Africa','Spain','Sweden','Switzerland','Thailand', 'United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom','United States','Uruguay','Venezuela','Vietnam','Zimbabwe'


GDP values for each country:

2255.225482,629.9553062,11601.63022,25306.82494,27266.40335,19466.99052,588.3691778,2890.345675,24733.62696,1445.760002,4803.398244,2618.876037,590.4521124,665.7982328,7122.938458,2639.54156,3362.4656,15378.16704,30860.12808,2579.115607,6525.541272,229.6769525,2242.689259,27570.4852,23016.84778,1334.646773,402.6953275,6047.200797,394.1156638,385.5793827,1414.072488,5745.981529,837.7464011,1206.991065,27715.52837,18937.24998,39578.07441,478.2194906,16684.21278,279.2204061,5345.213415,6288.25324,1908.304416,274.8728621,14646.42094,40034.85063,672.1547506,3359.517402,36152.66676,3054.727742,33529.83052,3825.093781,15428.32098,33630.24604,39170.41371,2699.123242,21058.43643,28272.40661,37691.02733,9581.05659,5671.912202,757.4009286,347.7456605
```

I am trying to format a text file using dataframe. All I want is transform the data into  2 columns with countries and GDP as header. I tried a couple of things but nothing seems to be working.

Is there an easier way to achieve it?

This is my code and it is throwing error.

```py
df=pd.read_csv(r'Countries with GDP.txt')
df1=df.T
lst1=(df1.iloc[:,0])
lst2=(df1.iloc[:,2])
lists=[lst1,lst2]
df2= pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in lists], axis=1)
df2
df2.columns =["Countries", "GDP"]
print(df2)
```

Comment: The file you linked to is not accessible, why not post some sample data?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\techy\DS-Python\Practise\GDP dataset\Countries with GDP.txt',skiprows=1,header=None)
df2=df.T
df2.columns = ['Countries', 'b','GDP']
df3=df2.drop(['b'], axis = 1) 
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
#display(df4)
df4.dtypes
df4['GDP']=pd.to_numeric(df4['GDP']).astype(float).round(2)
df4
```